# Kucoin futures API [python] - "code":"429000","msg":"Too Many Requests"

Tags: python, http-status-code-429, kucoin

I have a problem when I send an order to kucoin exchange with the API.

> "code":"429000","msg":"Too Many Requests"

It seems that my code send too many requests to Kucoin,
my IP address exceed the rate limit (the request rate limit is 30 times/3s).

It happen when I create only one order,
when I create an order,
I only have 3 requests:

1. to get Wallet balance
2. to get the contract size of a symbol
3. to create an order

1. get Wallet balance:

   ```
    def get_usdt_balance():
        try:    
            acc_balance = exchange.fetch_balance()
            return acc_balance['USDT']['free']

        except Exception as e:
            print("an exception occured - {}".format(e))
            return False
   ```
2. get the contract size of a symbol:

   ```
    def get_contractSize(symbol):
            contractsize= exchange.market(symbol)['contractSize']
            return contractsize
   ```
3. create an order

   ```
    def order(side, quantity, symbol):
        i = 0
        while i < 10:
            i += 1
            try:
                params = {'leverage': 15} 
                order =  exchange.create_order(
                    symbol=symbol, 
                    side=side, 
                    type='market', 
                    amount=quantity,
                    params=params)

            except Exception as e:
                print("an exception occured - {}".format(e))
                print ('- Retry n°',i,'...')
                time.sleep(11)
                continue

            else:
                print ("ORDER EXECUTED")
                print(f"sending order {side} - {symbol}")
                i == 0
                return order
   ```

As you can see in the last request, I should set up a "retry if fail" because the 429 error always come, the code wait 11 seconds, and retry, sometime it should retry 6 times to work.
So I'll lose more than one minute retrying, (its a scalping strategy I cannot wait that much) for only one order (3 requests) for only one account.

So how can we explain that the code exceed the request rate limit with only 3 requests?

Answer (score 1):

As of March 8, 2023, it seems that Kucoin is doing a bit better in terms of 429-Too Many Requests. The best you can do is just retrying after 100ms. I haven't found any other way. Those errors are very annoying and random.

```
pip install retrying
```

```py
from retrying import retry


def retry_on_429_too_many_requests(e):
    if '429' in str(e):
        logger.warning(f'Retry on 429: {str(e)}.')
        return True
    return False


@retry(stop_max_attempt_number=9, wait_fixed=100, retry_on_exception=retry_on_429_too_many_requests)
def request_to_kucoin(*args, **kwargs):
    pass # make a request to Kucoin.
```

Answer (score 0):

a bit improved algorithm of @Philippe Remy solution
with less often notifications:

```
begin
  result = @http.send(method, u, headers)
  if result.code == "429"
    sleep 100
    raise Retry
  end
rescue Retry
  handle_retries retries += 1, url, data
  retry
end

def handle_retries retries, url, data
  debug_data = {retries: retries, url: url, data: data}
  if retries % 10 == 0
    puts "Retry more than 10 times", debug_data
  end
  raise "Too much http retries" if retries % 50 == 0
end
```